# how to create custom access logs for user activity tracking datewise in laravel 5 and above?

Tags: laravel

i am new in Laravel and now i have to create a custom access log for tracking user activity and it's information like ,IP name and operation performed by the user. if anyone know please help me ,thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a tracker package for this: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can find a config file `app.php` in `config/app.php` path open this file and find this configuration for logs.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logging Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
|
*/

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

In laravel there are four default settings for logging.

In your case you can change this **single** to **daily**

Also you can add this into your **.env** file

```
 APP_LOG=daily
```

For more info [Check Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#configuration)

Comment: i have already done this, but after doing this it will only create log daywise and i also want to record user information and activity also means like user IP, Url's hits by user etc

Comment: @Manishp042 check `bootstrap/app.php` file. There you can define a custom log file name. But its for global, make that in dynamic to create different log files